# Set Label on "Text - Link" in NativeScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, nativescript

I want to insert some privacy-stuff into my app. To do so I would like to simply add a label to the bottom of my page where I link to a website. Basically it should look like:

Privacystuff can be found [**here**](https://www.google.com).

Basically the "here"-keyword should be clickable and it should be formatted in a different way. Whenever I try it with 2 Labels he displays the texts within two rows - which is not what I want. It could be a workaround to do this in a GridLayout, but there has to be another way. Does anyone know, how I can format it like that?

Comment: You should be able to use a formatted string and include an anchor tag

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. [Here](https://www.codeply.com/go/wAt3GDaK4V) it is. If it's an issue with the font-size, you can always resize the font with a media query.

Comment: @cwanjt That solution is sadly not working in NativeScript, since the Code is converted into native Android/iOS-Code and you can't access e.g. paragraph-tags AND a label is not allowed to be a container for other elements.

Comment: The formatted String seems to do it, thanks @mast3rd3mon

Comment: I'll add it as an answer so other people can find it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `<FormattedString>` tag which should allow you to include an anchor tag and other basic html tags

Comment: Worked, but the span-elements are not formatting the given text (so there are no linebreaks), do you know how to "autoformat" it?

Comment: you should be able to use the escaped html code of `&#x000a;` for a breakline

Comment: In that case I would need to know where I need to insert a linebreak. I suppose, that this solution would not work for all possible devices (since the screen-size is not always the same.

Comment: oh, i get you, there should be a textwrap or wordwrap property like there is on labels

Comment: you should be able to add `textWrap="true"` to the label tag and it should wrap over lines without adding linebreaks manually

Comment: Does this work using Spans? I couldn't get it done. Please provide some code.

Comment: @Rakesh Yes, it does. It works with any standard html element (to my knowledge, I cant say I've tried all of them). What code would you like providing? Googling "Nativescript FormattedString" should yield enough results

Comment: FormattedString with html link in it is what I am looking for.

Comment: @Rakesh then just use something like ```<FormattedString><a href="/someLink"></a></FormattedString>```

Comment: It doesnt work under label. Sample Example https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=ijIhwX

Comment: @GeorgeS can you provide a sample of what you have tried that doesnt work?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon Sorry I cannot and do not remember anymore so I have deleted my comment. The usages for FormattedString seem to be quite limited and poorly documented anyway. Thanks.